# css doesn't apply at all

Tags: html, css

Its very strange, when I run my page css style doesn't apply to the elements. Ex. top_login. When I try to debug in firebug it doesn't show that any css style was applied. Here is fiddle feed http://jsfiddle.net/rPyn8/7/. It works and all styles are applied there. But if try to link css file it doesn't work. To replicate this issue need create local files and open it in browser

Comment: Could you please provide an example that DOESN'T work for you? :-)

Comment: Have you tried validating the actual web page this is on? Malformed html syntax can throw hicups on properly rendering css on your webpage.

Comment: @Horst Gutmann on fiddle it works because it include css to the <style> tag but if you save all on files and open page it will not work

Comment: Which style is not being applied? Please be more specific. Styles seem to be applied for me when I look at your fiddle.

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy well, for your /css path to work I'd also have to serve them using an httpd and access the files via something like http://localhost/testpage.html :-) Just copying everything into a folder won't work here.

Comment: Not saying this is the cause of it.. But it is not valid xhtml as is your doctype(from first glance this is what I noticed), for instance the input tag should be like this:
<input type="hidden" name="adminlogin" value="true"/>

One more possible thing... Perhaps you need to clear your browser cache?

Comment: Also, please post your CSS into this location: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator you will see 3 errors that could definitely cause issues.

Comment: i tried in different browsers to avoid cache issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css has some error.  for example `cursor:hand` is not css property and form is tag so dont you tag name as a class name

[check here](http://jsfiddle.net/rPyn8/10/) you css working fine

Comment: `hand` is supported CSS value for `cursor` property up to IE8 and it's perfectly fine to have a class named `form`.

Comment: its working fine on fiddle but if you try to link it, as a page it won't

Comment: @strelok: support means is not it is displaying result, it means it should follow the rules

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy: you just need change css path to this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/admin.css"/> or it can be  just like <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin.css"/>

Answer (score 1):

Your path is incorrect.If stylesheet is in "css" folder in your main directory then
change :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/admin.css"/>
```

TO

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin.css"/>
```

Comment: I have tried downloading your code and making a HTML page. It works with this path.

Answer (score 1):

Here its working when I tried to include your css in the head part like this

```
<head>
 <style>
put your css here
 </style>
 </head>
```

You just check your css path.I think there is something wrong.Make your css link like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/admin.css"/>
```

Try to validate your html codes.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work on your local machine (from the file system folder, not a web server) is because of absolute path in your  tag.

Your file structure should be:

```
MyTestFolder
  |-- css
  |   |-- admin.css
  |-- test.html
```

You `<link>` tag in the html page should be:

```
<link href="css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Also in your `admin.css` you are using rooted paths to resources `/images/admin/center_form.gif` etc. you should make them relative paths (from the location of the CSS file by default): `images/admin/center_form.gif`. Change all of them

So expanding your directory structure, it should look similar to:

```
MyTestFolder
  |-- css
      |-- images
          |-- admin
              |--center_form.gif
  |   |-- admin.css
  |-- test.html
```

Comment: it works from the webserver. css folder in the html root so both pathes are correct but css still is not applied

Comment: @OleksandrKhavdiy does Firebug report a 404 in the "Net" tab for the CSS file?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in .htaccess. The path is correct but there is some rules need to change